# error TS1238: Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression

Tags: typescript

I recently started learning TypeScript and just started taking decorator. There is such an example in the course, but for some reason it doesn’t work for me. When using tsc it gives the following error. Please tell me how to fix the code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBXDV.png)

```
interface IUserService {
    users: number;
    getUsersInDatabase(): number;
}

function nullUser(target: Function){
    target.prototype.users = 0;
}

@nullUser
class UserService implements IUserService {
    users: number = 1000;

    getUsersInDatabase(): number {
        return this.users;
    }
}


console.log(new UserService().getUsersInDatabase())
```

There may be an error in tsconig, maybe the required lines were not opened

```
"experimentalDecorators": true,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `experimentalDecorators = true` in ts.config or use `tsc --experimentalDecorators` , you can look at [document](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorators)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

Comment: its was set before

Comment: @sniks have you try used `tsc --experimentalDecorators` ?

Comment: It worked!! Thank you very much, but this is strange, I don’t understand why it doesn’t work through ts.config

Comment: @sniks if you specify input files by using `tsc filename.ts`, `ts.config` will be ignored